# Running "stand-alone" python scripts on nginx

Tags: python, nginx

I want to run python scripts that output a similar format to this using nginx:

```
content-type: text/plain;charset=utf-8
content-length: 14

Hello, world!
```

They also handle compression internally by looking at accept-encoding request headers.
How can I run these scripts with nginx?
I am currently banging my head to the wall with this.

With apache, you could:

```
#/etc/apache2/python_exec.include
<Directory "/var/www/localhost">
    Options +ExecCGI
    AddHandler cgi-script .py
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Then include that in a `<VirtualHost>` block and give the .py files execute permission.

`/var/www/localhost/hello.py` to generate the example output:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
headers = [ 'content-type: text/plain;charset=utf-8' ]
body = b'Hello, world!\n' #this could be compressed, too, with the according information appended to headers
headers.append('content-length: {}'.format(len(body)))
sys.stdout.buffer.write('\r\n'.join(headers + ['', '']).encode('utf-8'))
sys.stdout.buffer.write(body)
```

Comment: See this article https://cuasan.wordpress.com/2015/01/25/simple-cgi-web-app-testing-setup-with-python-cgi-and-nginxuwsgi/. Apache and nginx are not same so you need some extra stuff